# Mark Gmail inbox mail tagged as the mail address

Tags: gmail

I use the "Check mail from other accounts (using POP3)" feature in Gmail. There are two other accounts I check mail from.

Emails from one account is tagged as the email address, that's so handy as I know this mail is fetched from that account.

However, the other mail does not. How can I set this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. GO TO SETTINGS
2. click on filter
3. in the to field put the email address in which you are retrieving
   from
4. click create filter with this search to test
5. then select the features you want
6. such as apply label and skip inbox if you only want it showing in
   your label.
7. if you select apply label you can create a new one or select a
   premade one
8. click create filter

Or follow the link in google's help menu
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35088

Hope this helps.